# how to edit PATH in bashrc

Tags: bashrc, paths

I edit PATH and just insted $PATH i write SPATH sooo I'm stock in login loop

and with root terminal try to login and edit PATH

so,
I don't know how to get bashrc with which command and how to edit PATH

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: In my ubuntu, PATH is not set in .bashrc, but in .profile

Comment: @jean-marie tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may know a few of these details, but I'm hoping to provide a list that will help you get through this.

1. `.bashrc` is found in a user's home directory.

   - `/home/usera/.bashrc`
   - `/root/.bashrc`
2. `$PATH` should be `export`'d for persistence and sub-shells.
3. You will likely only ADD to `$PATH`, and be careful not to reset it completely.

   - **BAD** `export PATH="/less/important/path:/lesser/important/path"`
   - **GOOD** `export PATH="${PATH}:/less/important/path:/lesser/important/path"`
4. The system will use the first found match, starting with directories on the left or beginning of the `$PATH` list.

If you find yourself with a really messed up configuration file, take a look at `/etc/skel`, and either copy that over, or use it as a reference for this and other configuration files provided to new users.

Answer (score 2):

For editing path and saving it permanentaly, u can use vi editors for that.

1. Go to your home directory:

   cd ~
2. type this command:

   sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

this will ask you for root password, as you want to set the path.

3. make a variable `HOME = /home/user/data`   -> as your home to access the information.
   and use this variable like:

   PATH = ${HOME}/path_to_the_desired_application

before exiting the bashrc file, save the modified changes...
This should work and you can edit your path in bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Open root terminal(may be in [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) chosen at boot) and edit .bashrc with following command: replace "youruser" with actual user name

```
nano /home/youruser/.bashrc
```

Fix a typo and try to login as that user.

Comment: in step 2 i have to edit PATH in bashrc but there is not anything about PATH

Comment: @Husen Do check bashrc of root as well if you are confident that you modified bashrc.